# How can a Request Tracker `scrip` insert multiple IP addresses in RT4's new IP Address custom field?

Tags: regex, rt

RT4 allows for a new CustomField consisting of a validated ipv4 or ipv6 address, and also allows for multiple values.  This allows me to have an "IP Addresses" custom field that has several addresses for a ticket.

I cannot seem to get a `scrip` that will accept multiple addresses from an email (or any `correspond` event for that matter), only one address will be accepted.

The `scrip` I am using is a custom action that looks like this:

```
my $Ticket = $self->TicketObj;
my $Transaction = $self->TransactionObj;
my $body = $Transaction->Content();
my $cf = new RT::CustomField($RT::SystemUser);
my $id;
my $msg;
my $queue = 'Testes';

#---IPS
if($body =~ /X-addresses\:(.*)\n/i){
my $iplist = $1;
($id,$msg) = $cf->LoadByNameAndQueue (Name=>'addresses', Queue=>$queue);
($id,$msg) = $Ticket->AddCustomFieldValue (Field => $cf, Value =>$iplist);
}
return(1);
```

I'm not opposed to being told I'm going about this the wrong way; present practice for my RT install is to have a web form submit requests, currently that request will have an IP address field that is picked up by a similar `scrip` (in addition to x-fqdn, x-contact, x-OS, and other information being collected) and I was thinking a comma-seperated list of mixed ipv4,ipv6 could be snarfed in one line and, as long as RT's address parser validated it, we'd be in business.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, except those that direct me to the hideous BestPractical wiki, I have combed through every tumbleweed-ridden page and come up empty.

Comment: This looks like perl.  If so, you will probably get more responses if you add the perl tag.

Comment: OK, I was curious about that but was not sure about local customs.

Comment: @David, RT scrips are not precisely perl, though they look very similar.

Comment: If the grizzly `perl` wizards grow restless, I have no problems pulling the tag out.  I don't want to be spammy.

Comment: Ah - ok. Didn't realize that. Thanks for the clarification and disregard what I said about using the perl tag.

Comment: I noticed that you use the term 'scrip' instead of 'script'. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, RT uses a series of `scrip`s to perform various logic to a transaction on a ticket.  I don't know the origin of the term or the nuances of it, but I usually think of them as "prescriptions".  

They're more like a `procmail` recipe or `sieve` rule than what you'd normally consider a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you only perform the regex once, and only get the first match. You sound like you want to loop through and find as many matches as you can. To demonstrate I made some quick perl scripts (I don't have my RT installation in front of me, so I have left out the RT specific stuff).

The first works very similarly to yours, grabbing the first match and printing it:

```
~/perl/test$ cat testRegex.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $body = <<END;
X-Addresses:1.2.3.4
X-Addresses:2.3.4.5
X-Addresses:10.0.0.1
some other text
another line of content
END

if($body =~ /X-addresses\:(.*)\n/i){
        my $iplist = $1;
        print $iplist, "\n";
}
```

The output of this script is:

```
~/perl/test$ ./testRegex.pl
1.2.3.4
```

The second demonstrates the syntax you want to use:

```
~/perl/test$ cat testRegex2.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $body = <<END;
X-Addresses:1.2.3.4
X-Addresses:2.3.4.5
X-Addresses:10.0.0.1
some other text
another line of content
END

while ($body =~ /X-addresses\:(.*)\n/gi){
        my $ip = $1;
        print $ip, "\n";
}
```

The output for this script is:

```
~/perl/test$ ./testRegex2.pl
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
10.0.0.1
```

Instead of printing the $ip variable, you can pass it in to another function or method, such as AddCustomFieldValue.

To explain: The regex is changed slightly to use the g (or global) switch, indicating that it will search through the entire string rather than stopping at the first match
The if is changed to a while - you could probably do this with an if somehow - I just don't know how. If you did, you would have to get all the matches in one variable - likely an array. After that you would need to iterate through the array anyway running AddCustomFieldValue for each element. My perl is not strong enough to figure it out using an if, but I think it's a little more readable and neat with a while anyway.

Comment: I think I follow the explanation you are providing, and the scrip appears to be OK with a `while`.  I'm not sure on the insertion as a custom field though, the current stanza in my `OnCorrespond` scrip looks like this: [gist](https://gist.github.com/3866253). 

— But only the first match is being inserted.  Any ideas?  Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: hmmmm, I'm only guessing here, but it could be that the $cf->LoadByNameAndQueue should only occur once (and that it fails when it comes back to try again). If that were the case I would just move that line above the while line. However because that's more of a guess, you may want to add::x

Comment: ...However because that's more of a guess, you may want to add $RT::Logger->debug statements beneath both the LoadByNameAndQueue and the AddCustomFieldValue methods to output the id and message you are returning from them. eg: `$RT::Logger->debug("ID: " . $id . " MSG: " . $msg);` then increase RT's logging level to debug. damn 5 minute limit on edits...

Comment: I believe the reason it wasn't working was because I was testing with a scrip action of "On Correspondence" and was then using a Comment.  It needs to be a Reply, your debug suggestion revealed I was calling my old scrip behavior still since it wasn't considering it Correspondence.  #facepalm.  I'm still hacking on this to make sure but so far it looks like I can get this rolling thanks to you!  Now my form guy will probably tell me he wants it comma-seperated or something.